# Automatic fill-in of columns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I collect data on birds in my city. In my column, I have the Names of the Birds, their scientific name and their abbreviation.

Now I am searching for a simple solution to simplify the work. I would like to have an automatic fill-in of the columns. So if I write in the first column `"Robin"` in the second column automatically appears `"Erithacus rubecula"` and in the third `"R"`.

Is it possible?

Comment: I have an Excel-table (xls) with the informations. The column heading ist not the same, but it could be changed.

Answer (score 9):

*Assuming you have an Excel-Sheet called BirdLookup containing the three columns LookupBird, LookupScientific and LookupAbbrevation with no geometry and a Pointlayer with the three columns Bird, Scientific and Abbrevation, you can do it like below*

[image]

First, create a relation: Go to <kbd>Project</kbd> --> <kbd>Properties</kbd> --> <kbd>Relations</kbd>. Click on <kbd>+ Add Relation</kbd>

Set it up the following:

- Give it a `Name` you like, e.g. `BirdRelation`
- Set the `strength` to `Association`
- Choose your `Excel-File` as `Referenced (parent)` Layer
- Choose your `Geometrylayer` as `Referencing (child)` Layer
- Choose your `Link-Field` for both. E.g. LookupBird and Bird

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Now <kbd>right click</kbd> your `Geometrylayer` in your legend and open the layer <kbd>properties</kbd>. Navigate to <kbd>Attributes Form</kbd>.

On your `Birds-Field`, choose `Relation Reference` as `Widget-Type`. If its not filled automatically, choose your just created relation as `Relation`. Set your `Display-Expression` to the value you want to show, most likely LookupBird.

[image]

On your `Scientific-Field`, choose `Value Relation` as `Widget-Type`.

- Choose your `Lookup-Layer` as `Layer`
- Your Field, you have choosen in your relation as `Key-Column`
- The Field which content you want here as `Value-Column`
- Enter the expression `"LookupBird"  =  current_value('Bird')` as `Filter`. The first one (`"LookupBird"`) refers to your relation field in the other layer. `'Bird'` refers to your relation field in your active layer. Replace these with your values.

[image]

On your `Abbrevation-Field`, choose `Value Relation` as `Widget-Type`.

- Choose your `Lookup-Layer` as `Layer`
- Your Field, you have choosen in your relation as `Key-Column`
- The Field which content you want here as `Value-Column`
- Enter the expression `"LookupBird"  =  current_value('Bird')` as `Filter`. The first one (`"LookupBird"`) refers to your relation field in the other layer. `'Bird'` refers to your relation field in your active layer. Replace these with your values.

[image]

Confirm your settings with <kbd>OK</kbd>. Example result:

[image]

Comment: This is a wonderful answer ! Including the animation and explanations

Answer (score 5):

You can use a virtual field (using field calculator) and define it's content with an expression like this:

```
if (name = 'Robin', 'Erithacus rubecula', '')
```

where `name` is the name of the attribute field where you enter "Robin". So every time you enter "Robin" in the field name, the field defined with this expression will return "Erithacus rubecula". You must probably update the field or close/reopen the attribute table to see the changes.

*Screenshot: in the layer properties, fields tab you see which fields you have, which are virtual ones and the expression that creates to actual value:*
[image]